# PHP session_start as security

Tags: php, security, session

I'm making registration/login pages for a project.

Today I've heard that `mysql_` extensions is already dispatched and I't better to use `PDO`.
So I understood that my little knowledge of PHP is already old.

Now I'm little bit confused whether it is good or not to use `sessions` as security.

To find some altenative to sessions

Comment: I think you need to make this question a little more concise.

Comment: What do you mean by "use sessions as security"? Could you explain, maybe show some examples?

Comment: You can use `Mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I'm mean if there is some better alternatives to session

Comment: session support is not about to be deprecated if that is your question.

Comment: Thank you Dave, that was question )) I asked it really bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are not intrinsically secure. When using sessions in PHP, you do have to concern yourself with basic session security:

- Exposed data

  - especially in shared hosting environments
- Session fixation
- Session hijacking

I recommend you read [chapter 4 of Essential PHP Security, by Chris Shiflett](http://phpsecurity.org/contents#ch04).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whether its save to trust the information you've put in the $_SESSION: yeah, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you getting mixed up with cookies. Sessions for logins are essential. They should be secure. Remember Me systems use persistant login cookies and those can sometimes be vulnerable to security holes when not done correctly. But a normal login system shouldnt need that.

http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/